# Plugin para organizar eventos em forma de calendário

Tags: jquery-plugins

Existe algum plugin de preferencia (html5 css3) para organizar eventos?, preciso mostrar todos os dias do mes de forma organizada, gostaria de informar ao publico os dias que já estão ocupados, e permitir cadastrar um novo evento apenas clicando na data do calendário.

Comment: Apenas uma sugestão, existe milhares de plugins para essa finalidade, você pode achar isso facilmente em uma busca no google, quando construir sua pergunta pensa nas tags que mais faça sentido, "site" "html" "script" são extremamente genéricos.
http://fullcalendar.io/

Comment: Eu já usei o [fullcalendar](http://fullcalendar.io/) e acho que é o melhor que tem. Dá pra fazer tudo isso que tu falou, é só ler a documentação no site. Tenta implementar pelo menos o básico, para que possamos ajudar depois, se for preciso